# Call a server and GET token from response with Objective C

Tags: json, objective-c, parsing, post, get

I'm making a view for my App where a user has to login.
So I have to call my server for 2 times:

- the first call (with the GET method) let me obtain a response containing a cookie (named XSFR-TOKEN) which I have to extract and use later for the second call.
- The second one (with the POST method) is a call to which I have to send in the request body (in JSON) several parameters (username, password, client_id and the token previously obtained). The response of this call will redirect me to a fictitious URL.

When I do the first call in my function, it works succesfully but I can't extract and save the token from the responseString in orther to use it later.

I'm stuck because I don't know how to continue.
Thank you for helping me.

```
    -(void) makeLoginRequest {
    NSLog(@"LoginFirstStepViewController - makeLoginRequest");
    
    // Preparing URL
    NSString *loginURL = SELFBLUE_LOGIN_REDIRECT_OAUTH;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginURL];
    
    // Initialize the request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    // Set request method
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
     
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            NSString *errorMsg = error.userInfo[@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
            errorMsg = (errorMsg) ? errorMsg:NSLocalizedString(@"unexpected_error", nil);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.view makeToast:errorMsg duration:4.0 position:CSToastPositionCenter];
            });
            return;
        } else {
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
        }
        
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSLog(@"makeLoginRequest: %@", response);
        // Status code 200 allows me to continue, otherwise I had an error.
        if (httpResponse.statusCode !=200) {
            NSLog(@"%ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
            [self showMessageAndUnwindForHttpError:httpResponse.statusCode];
            return;
        }
                
        //EXTRACT THE TOKEN
        
        
       //WRITE CODE FOT POST REQUEST

    }];
    [task resume];
    }
```

Comment: ANd what's the output of `NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);`? Is it JSON? XML?

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `error.userInfo[@"NSLocalizedDescription"]`, prefer use `error.localizedDescription` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror/1414418-localizeddescription?language=objc). If you're annoyed with default, value, at least use the key `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` directly, not `@"NSLocalizedDescription"`.

Comment: @Larme It's an XML that returns a row in which there is the token:
<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="_csrf" value="b9be4787-8a01-4569-9446-f2e33e28b1bd"/> that I want to save somehow.

Comment: So you want to know how to "parse XML" (that's keywords for your search). So parse it.

Comment: @Larme Yes, I think that's what I need. Sorry for my language but I'm very new to coding so I'm still learning how to write and speak.